# trouble with NSFastEnumeration protocol and ARC

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having trouble implementing the NSFastEnumeration protocol while migrating Objective-C code to ARC.
Could someone tell me, how to get rid of the following warnig (see code snippet)? Thanks in advance.

```
// I changed it due to ARC, was before
// - (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState*) state objects: (id*) stackbuf count: (NSUInteger) len
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState: (NSFastEnumerationState*) state objects: (__unsafe_unretained id *) stackbuf count: (NSUInteger) len
{
    ... 
    *stackbuf = [[ZBarSymbol alloc] initWithSymbol: sym]; //Warning: Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment
    ... 
}

- (id) initWithSymbol: (const zbar_symbol_t*) sym
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        ... 
    }
    return(self);
}
```

Comment: Try changing `__unsafe_unretained` to `__autoreleasing`. From *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes*: "__autoreleasing is used to denote arguments that are passed by reference (id *) and are autoreleased on return."

Comment: changing `__unsafe_unretained` to `__autoreleasing` unfortunately yields a new warning: Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:': '__unsafe_unretained id *' vs '__autoreleasing id *'

Comment: You did change it in both the `.h` and `.m` file right?  In fact the compiler will use `__autoreleasing` by default, so perhaps the best thing would be to change to back as it was pre-ARC.

Comment: No, I can't change `.h`, as it's part of the NSFastEnumeration Protocol [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html)

Comment: Well all I can say is that there is a definition *somewhere* which still contains `__unsafe_unretained`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ARC, something has to hold a strong or autoreleasing reference to each object, otherwise it will be released (just as the warning says). Because `stackbuf` is `__unsafe_unretained`, it's not going to hang onto the `ZBarSymbol` for you.

If you create a temporary autoreleasing variable and stash your object there, it will live until the current autorelease pool is popped. You can then point `stackbuf` to it without complaint.

```
ZBarSymbol * __autoreleasing tmp = [[ZBarSymbol alloc] initWithSymbol: sym];
*stackbuf = tmp;
```

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you miss a `=` after `tmp`